# Different behavior of XQuery execution in two system

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

There are two systems available(Let's say System A & System B) with MarkLogic v10.0-6 installed in them.

I want to execute this function in System A & System B,

```
declare function local:dateTimeCompare($documentURI as xs:string) as xs:boolean {
  let $firstDateTime := doc($documentURI)/firstDateTimeXpath
  let $secondDateTime := doc($documentURI)/secondDateTimeXpath
  return $firstDateTime > $secondDateTime 
};

local:dateTimeCompare("/sample.xml")
```

**Current Behaviour:**
The given query is getting executed properly in System A but not in System B

It means, If I want to execute the above query properly in System B then I have to explicitly cast `$firstDateTime`  and `$secondDateTime`  to `xs:dateTime` and it started working.

**Expected Behaviour:**
The same query should execute in both the machine without casting to `xs:dateTime`.

**My question is** - Why I am seeing two different behaviors?
It means System B should not expect explicit casting to xs:dateTime.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably have schemas defined in System A that indicate the type of that data.

Comment: Thank you @hunterhacker for your comment, there is no schema defined in System A, What could be another reason?

Comment: What are the `QName` for the dateTime elements? Are you using TDE or anything else that might be relevant? Explicit type casts might not be a bad idea anyhow. You could create another function that accepts two dateTime items and returns a boolean. Then it might auto-cast to dateTime even if it's being seen as string or something else.

Comment: and/or you can change the last axis step to invoke the `xs:dateTime()` function: `let $firstDateTime := doc($documentURI)/firstDateTimeXpath/xs:dateTime(.)`

Comment: I would encourage comparing dates with explicit casts. It makes sure dates are compared correctly even if they specify different timezones.

Comment: next to using `xs:dateTime(.)` as suggested by Mads, you can also use strong typing: `let $firstDateTime as xs:dateTime := ...`. That also saves confusion in case the XPath or content isn't as robust as you might expect.